# Find "ul" elements that does not have "li" elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So lets say i have this html code

```
<ul id="mainUL">
<li>
   <ul></ul>
</li>
<li>
   <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>
   <ul>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to find those ul that does not contain any li elements? My code is quite dynamic so it is hard for me to insert a class or id to append those ul. Do i use jquery `.find()` or jquery `.children()`? And how do I apply these `$('ul')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combine of [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to do this work.

```
$("ul:not(:has(li))")
```

```js
$("ul:not(:has(li))").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mainUL">
<li>
   <ul></ul>
</li>
<li>
   <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```